Why are just 4 nested CPIs allowed?
What is the motivation behind limiting the maximum number of nested CPIs (max_invoke_stack_height) to just 4?

The lore behind this is that,
Trent(from Solana Labs) at the time asked Armani(anchorlang creator) what the call depth for CPIs should be and he said 4.

The runtime is very inefficiently executing CPIs. It basically nests VMs when going down a level in the CPI stack. The 4 limit is just a best guess for preventing excess memory consumption and general chaos.
Twitter ref


Wow, thank you for the insight!
Given the motivation behind this design decision, though, I'm not sure whether to laugh or to be sad regarding the matter...

I heard about plans to change this, but I can't cite any quality sources behind it.
